# Alternative to using KSOAP for accessing WebService from Android application due to KSOAP jar size

Tags: android

I am adding `ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar` as an external jar into my Android project. I'm using the SOAP API to access some .NET web services from my Android application.

The size of the `ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar` is 96 KB so I don't want to increase the size of the Android application by using the external jar.

What's an alternate option to access a .NET webservice from an Android application?

Comment: he size of the ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar is 96 KB & so I dont want to increase the size of the Android application by using the external jar



     Can you share why adding 96 KB to your application size is an issue for you?

Comment: 96KB are a lot, if you use a G1 :P
Actually, I dont know any other Libraries for SOAP. You could, of course, build you own one. I think you dont need all those methods of KSOAP. But it takes time and inventing the wheel, which was already invented needs time and could be exhausting...
Are 96KB worth it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a late answer but it seams like nobody has attempted it before. I made my own service client class, its not as generic as ksoap2 but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class service_client extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private static ProgressDialog dialog;

    private static int ReadTimeout = 10000;
    private static int ConnectTimeout = 10000;
    private static String urlString = "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?";
    private static String namespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET";
    private static String soapAction = namespace +"/";
    private String[] cacheParams;
    private Context context;

    public service_client(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        try {
            if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...", false);
        }
        catch (Exception ignored)
        {}
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... Params)
    {
        try {
            cacheParams = Params;

            // Create soap message
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("<v:Envelope xmlns:v=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><v:Body><")
                    .append(Params[0])
                    .append(" xmlns=\"")
                    .append(namespace)
                    .append("\">");
            for (String param : Params) {
                String[] parameter_data = param.split("\\|", 2);
                if (parameter_data.length == 2) {
                    sb.append("<")
                            .append(parameter_data[0])
                            .append(">")
                            .append(parameter_data[1])
                            .append("</")
                            .append(parameter_data[0])
                            .append(">");
                }
            }
            sb.append("</")
                    .append(Params[0])
                    .append("></v:Body></v:Envelope>");
            String content = sb.toString();

            // create post for soap message
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // this needs to be HttpsURLConnection if you are using ssl
            connection.setReadTimeout(ReadTimeout);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(ConnectTimeout);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(content.length()));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); // comment this line out if you dont want to compress all service calls
            connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction + Params[0]);

            // Get soap response
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            String response = "";
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            BufferedReader br;
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                br = connection.getContentEncoding().equals("gzip") ?
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getUnZippedInputStream(connection.getInputStream()))) :
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("HTTP ERROR: " + responseCode);
            }

            // Extract data
            int index = response.indexOf(Params[0] + "Result>") + 7+Params[0].length();
            response = response.substring(index, response.indexOf("</"+Params[0], index));

            // release all resources
            br.close();
            connection.disconnect();

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.getClass().toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        try
        {
            if(result.equals("class java.net.ConnectException") || result.equals("class java.net.UnknownHostException") || result.equals("class java.net.SocketTimeoutException"))
            {
                //you can ask the user if they would like to retry as there was a network error
                //use the cacheParams to recall the method
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            catch (Exception ignored)
            {}
        }
    }

    //gzip compression
    private GZIPInputStream getUnZippedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
            /* workaround for Android 2.3
               (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131016/)
            */
        try {
            return (GZIPInputStream)inputStream;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            return new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

obviously this is an example soap service being used. Anyway this is how I call the service with this class:

```
new service_client(this).execute("GetWeather", //first param being the method name
            "CityName|Cape Town", //params are seperated by a '|' character for simplicity
            "CountryName|South Africa");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the size of the code added to only what is actually needed by using [Proguard](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html). You could also use [proguard with the maven android plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ProGuard) if you are building your app with maven.  Also if you are using it on Android you should be using the latest release (2.5.1) of the [ksoap2-android project](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/). And yes, imho it is worth the additional size for a reasonable app talking to a few web services or if you need to get things working sooner rather than later.