# Android can't read from URL

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm having trouble reading text from a file in the Android workspace using the URL class. I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException. The same exact code works outside of the Android workspace, so it must be a network or permissions issue. I've generated a basic text file from the link specified. 
It appears that it is failing on url.openStream.
Below is my code, followed by my manifest file (where I've added the uses-permissions line already.)

```
  static public String[] barList()
{ 
   ArrayList<String> bars = new ArrayList<String>();
   try{
       URL url = new URL("****");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
       String line = br.readLine();
       while(line != null)
       {
           bars.add(line);
           line = br.readLine();
       }
       br.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return (String[])bars.toArray();
}
```

Here is the manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="aexp.explist">
<application>
    <activity android:name=".ExpList" android:label="ExpList">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is the exception hinting at what happened? `e.getMessage()`

Comment: For some reason, the exception isn't catching when I debug the program. Instead of taking me to the catch block, it takes me to a "Class.class" file.

Comment: When this happens and you are in the DDMS perspective, click on the green "play" button to continue. Do this a few times if necessary and you should finally see the stack trace in the LogCat tab. By the way, I tested your code in my emulator with the Internet permission only and I did not get any errors.

Comment: I followed your advice, and have found I'm getting an "NetworkOnMainThreadException". I get this on the call to open the input stream from the url. I am attempting to run this on Android 3.2, API level 13.

Comment: I don't have access to my Android development box for the time being, but it looks like in the API you are targeting you are not allowed to perform network operations on the main thread. You are probably going to have to move this code to a thread, or maybe an AsyncTask. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your stream is zipped :
[GZIPInputStream fails with IOException in Android 2.3, but works fine in all previous releases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131016/gzipinputstream-fails-with-ioexception-in-android-2-3-but-works-fine-in-all-prev)

if you don't use a buffered input stream, can you read the url content ?

Also, I often use url.getContent and cast it to an inputstream, and this works, I am not familiar with url.openStream.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: On further examination, it fails on url.openStream. So it doesn't even reach the BufferedInput code before it fails. Trying to use (InputStream)url.getContent does not work either. It seems to me to possibly be a permissions issue. Perhaps with reading from an https website?

Comment: you would get a permission exception, not an ioexception. Anyhow, you grant internet permission to your app, it shouldn't be that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs correctly without throwing an exception if I paste it into and run it from my current project. I'm targeting sdk 4-8.

Answer (score -2):

- [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Hope that helps  :-)