# Calling webservice from android application without Ksoap

Tags: android

What would be best and simplest way to call Yahoo weather webservice/any json webservice in android?
Some people suggest not to use Ksoap for mobile application instead use Restful or Json webservice.

TIA
Bhaskar

Comment: this seems to be a more useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32198459/2027232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, use `HttpClient`, `HttpGet`, and `JSONObject`

Without any more details, this is probably similar to what you are attempting:  http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/

Comment: Thanks it worked so far. Now I am looking for list of available webservices which are restful and jason enabled. Like flight tracker and weather service etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another post where this is discussed:

[How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

If you really want to be simple, just embed the content of the message in a HttpClient (included with Android by default) and manually parse the result.

Here (http://breaking-catch22.com/?p=127) is a link to an example of calling a REST web service.

Comment: My  journey started from the same link you sent, but did not have much idea of restfull webservice initially so dropped that but djg's link, given below, just worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) does it, for example in this YouTube sample using HttpTransport and JSON:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg%2Fyoutube-jsonc-sample%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fapi%2Fclient%2Fsample%2Fyoutube